# Mysql database has reverted to an old time all of a sudden

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

We have a centos server which has a Mysql database and had an uptime of around 105 days before the incident. Suddenly we got notified that the server has restarted for apparently no reason (we are still investigating). But what happened is everything on the server is the same except the database. It's reverted to around 105 days ago. The reason I use the word "revert" is because not only the data is gone the modifications on the tables and some new tables that we made after that date are gone as well.
If anyone has an experience like that or that could help that would be really appreciated.

Some more info that maybe related:
We had a master/slave db arch using Galera. Both the databases are identical right now (data and structure).

Comment: Speak to your hosting provider

Comment: @MatBailie will do that. any guesses or similar experience?

Comment: *It's reverted to around 5 months ago.* 5 month = ~150 days which is over the uptime. So the only possible reason is that your data was restored/recovered completely from some ancient backup.

Comment: @Akina Wow that was a nice point. but actually I was wrong, after reading your comment the database is exactly back to 105 days which the slave server has the uptime. so It's like after the restart incident, database has gone back to what it was 105 days ago like the data wasn't persistent or something like that. Now if you have any other clues I'll gladly hear it out.

Comment: It sounds more like the hosting provider goofed.  You say "master/slave" and you say "Galera".  Those are related, but they imply different things; which is it?  How many nodes do you have?